# How to use Gabor filters for feature extraction from image?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, svm, gabor-filter

I want to apply Gabor filter for feature extraction from image then on the trained data I will be applying NN or SVM.I didn't applied batch processing though but it will be done or if you can help me with the machine learning part it will be great for me.Thank you.
Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob

img=glob.glob("C://Users//USER//Pictures//Saved Pictures//tuhin.jpg")

img = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]  
ret, labels = cv2.connectedComponents(img)
label_hue = np.uint8(179*labels/np.max(labels))
blank_ch = 255*np.ones_like(label_hue)
labeled_img = cv2.merge([label_hue, blank_ch, blank_ch])
labeled_img = cv2.cvtColor(labeled_img, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
labeled_img[label_hue==0] = 0
cv2.imshow('labeled.png', labeled_img)
cv2.waitKey()

def build_filters():
filters = []
ksize = 31
for theta in np.arange(0, np.pi, np.pi / 16):
    kern = cv2.getGaborKernel((ksize, ksize), 4.0, theta, 10.0, 0.5, 0, 
              ktype=cv2.CV_32F)
    kern /= 1.5*kern.sum()
    filters.append(kern)
    return filters

def process(img, filters):
    accum = np.zeros_like(img)
    for kern in filters:
        fimg = cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_8UC3, kern)
        np.maximum(accum, fimg, accum)
        return accum

filters=build_filters()
res1=process(img,filters)
cv2.imshow('result',res1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 3):

I can define more kernels just by changing the parameters such as theta,lamda that is  frequency and orientation.I can generate Gabor filter bank then I will apply various machine learning algorithm for classification.

code after batch processing:

```
import cv2
import os
import glob
import numpy as np


img_dir = "C://Users//USER//Pictures//Saved Pictures" 
data_path = os.path.join(img_dir,'*g')
files = glob.glob(data_path)
data = []
for f1 in files:
    img = cv2.imread(f1,0)
    data.append(img)
    img = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]  
    ret, labels = cv2.connectedComponents(img)
    label_hue = np.uint8(179*labels/np.max(labels))
    blank_ch = 255*np.ones_like(label_hue)
    labeled_img = cv2.merge([label_hue, blank_ch, blank_ch])
    labeled_img = cv2.cvtColor(labeled_img, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    labeled_img[label_hue==0] = 0
    cv2.imshow('labeled.png', labeled_img)
    cv2.waitKey()

    def build_filters():
        filters = []
        ksize = 31
        for theta in np.arange(0, np.pi, np.pi / 16):
            kern = cv2.getGaborKernel((ksize, ksize), 4.0, theta, 10.0, 0.5, 0, ktype=cv2.CV_32F)
            kern /= 1.5*kern.sum()
            filters.append(kern)
            return filters

    def process(img, filters):
        accum = np.zeros_like(img)
        for kern in filters:
            fimg = cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_8UC3, kern)
            np.maximum(accum, fimg, accum)
            return accum

    filters=build_filters()
    res1=process(img,filters)
    cv2.imshow('result',res1)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cv2.imwrite("checking.tif",res1)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a nice tutorial on texture extraction using gabor filter with scikit-image: http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.11.x/auto_examples/plot_gabor.html. You may want to have a look at it.

You may want to use deep learning / transfer learning (depending on how much data you have) to extract the features automatically instead of hand-crafted features.

Comment: You are saying that I don't have to edit this code and I just have to apply this code on numerous images for more data then applying machine learning algorithm.

Comment: @Akash yes, you need to change image file names :).

Comment: If I use *.jpg then applying a for loop and write the whole code with proper identation, will it be convenient?

Comment: I have now used batch processing and I want to save it in a particular folder ,how can I do that?

Comment: use skimage.io.imsave(pathtoimage)

Comment: File "H:\python-anaconda\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1917, in save
    raise ValueError('unknown file extension: {}'.format(ext))

ValueError: unknown file extension: